# Custom Spring (Boot) annotation: @ConditionalOnProperty with default key name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to create a custom Spring (Boot) annotation `@Country` that "inherits" `@ConditionalOnProperty`, but predefines the property key?

Given a some services that share a common interface

```
interface WizardService {
   void doMagic()
}
```

and a set of country specific implementations that are selected via `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "country", havingValue = "[iso-code]")`, i.e. the implementation is selected based on the value of the *country* property

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "country", havingValue = "de")
@Service
class WizardServiceGermany {
   @Override void doMagic() { System.out.println("Simsalabim!"); }
}

@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "country", havingValue = "en")
@Service
class WizardServiceGreatBritain {
   @Override void doMagic() { System.out.println("Wingardium Leviosa!"); }
}
```

is it possible to define a custom spring annotation which always sets the `name` property to "country" by default so that I can have an `@Country` annotation? For instance:

```
@Country("en")
@Service
class WizardServiceGreatBritain {
   @Override void doMagic() { System.out.println("Wingardium Leviosa!"); }
}
```

I tried creating a meta-annotation, but it gets ignored (while replacing it with its `@ConditionalOnProperty` equivalent works fine):

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "country")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
public @interface Country {

    @AliasFor(annotation = ConditionalOnProperty.class, attribute = "havingValue")
    String havingValue() default "";
}
```

Comment: Given the widespread support for meta annotations in Spring, I'd try annotating *your custom annotation itself* with `@ConditionalOnProperty` and checking if it works. See here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-meta-annotations for ways to expose the `havingValue` property and here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html for ways to alias properties

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I tried it in an SSCE and updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The problem is the actual value is not getting replaced with `havingValue` attribute. I mean if you debug this file `onPropertyCondition::getMatchOutcome` you will see that the value of `havingValue` is empty string instead of the value in your anntation

Comment: Looks like this(meta annotations) doesn't work for springboot Autoconfigure classes

Comment: The only thing you can do is: Implement your own custom condition.